# Geocoding requests to HERE API randomly fails

Tags: spring-boot, here-api

I am trying to geocode addresses with HERE API. I am not free plan. I try following code (Spring Boot in Kotlin):

```
override fun geocode(address: Address): Coordinate? {
        val uriString = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(endpoint)
            .queryParam("app_id", appId)
            .queryParam("app_code", appCode)
            .queryParam("searchtext", addressToSearchText(address))
            .toUriString()
        logger.info("Geocode requested with url {}", uriString)
        val response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriString, String::class.java)
        return response.body?.let {
            Klaxon().parse<GeocodeResponse>(it)
        }?.let {
            it.Response.View.firstOrNull()?.Result?.firstOrNull()
        }?.let {
            Coordinate(
                latitude = it.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
                longitude = it.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
            )
        }.also {
            if (it == null) {
                logger.warn("Geocode failed: {}", response.body)
            }
        }
    }
```

It turned out that when I call this method many times in a row, some requests returns empty responses, like this:

```
{  
   "Response":{  
      "MetaInfo":{  
         "Timestamp":"2019-04-18T11:33:17.756+0000"
      },
      "View":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

I could not figure out any rule why some requests fail. It seems to be just random.

However, when I try to call same URLs with `curl` of in my browser, everything works just fine.

I guess there is some limit for amount requests per seconds, but I could not find anything in HERE documentation.

Does anyone have an idea about the limit? Or may it be something else?

Comment: There is no rate limiting for Geocoder API. If you are still facing this issue, please provide your app_id(only) and the time of your request so that we can check our logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there was a problem with my code. Requests were failing for addresses having "special" symbols like ü and ö. The problem was with building request URL

```
val uriString = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(endpoint)
            .queryParam("app_id", appId)
            .queryParam("app_code", appCode)
            .queryParam("searchtext", addressQueryParam(address))
            .build(false)  // <= this was missed
            .toUriString()
```